Create new entity inside of PreInsertEventListener Hibernate
I am trying to automatically re-hash data when saved to the database using JPA.
The idea is that I have an entity that contains a list of other entities.
A has a reference to a @OneToMany "List<B> myBList"
B => has a @ManyToOne "A a"
B's hashs are based only on the entity's data.
A's hash is based on the entity's data and the hash of the list of B's
If any B is modified or created and added to A, I want to rehash the value of A.
However, in my PreInsert or PreUpdateEvent listener do not register any call to entityManager.save(a) or event.getSession().save(a).
B hash is properly modified by changing the Object[] state, but using b.getA(), modifying A and saving it does not work.
I am starting to wonder if that is even possible to do inside of event listeners.

This is not possible. The JPA specification only allows you to modify non-relationship attributes of the entity for which the lifecycle callback was triggered.
"A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked."
JPA Spec
The reason for it is that your persistence provider first checks if your code changed any managed entity. If that's the case, this change gets processed and that triggers the lifecycle callback.
If this callback modifies another entity object, as it is the case with your hash calculation, your persistence provider isn't aware of this modification and doesn't handle it.

Hello Thorben. I am asking about Hibernate's PreInsertEventListeners, not JPA @PreInsert events.
I assume there are some ways to make this possible, as Envers is able to intercept insertions, updates and deletions inside of transactions
